Confused about Proof of Theorem regarding equivalent conditions for a finite extension E/F with Galois Group G.
A Theorem in my textbook says the following: The following conditions are equivalent for a finite extension $E/F$. with Galois group $G=Gal(E/F)$:
(i) $F=E^G$ (where $E^G$ are the elements of $E$ fixed by all automorphisms in $G$)
(ii) every irreducible $p(x) \in F[x]$ with one root in $E$ is separable and has all its roots in $E$.
in the proof of (i) $\rightarrow$ (ii), they say:
"let α be a root of an irreducible polynomial $p(x) \in F[x]$ and let the distinct elements of the set $\{σ(α) : σ \in G\}$ be $α_1,...,α_n$.
Define $g(x) \in E[x]$ by:
$g(x) = \prod(x-α_i)$.
Now each of the $σ \in G$ permutes the $α_i$ ; so that each $σ$ fixes the coefficients of $g(x)$; that is, the coefficients of g(x) lie in $E^G=F$..."
My confusion is in the last part of what I wrote; why do the coefficients of $g(x)$ have to lie in $E^G=F$?
Thanks in advance!

Another way to see it is to note that the coefficients are symmetric functions of the roots, hence fixed under permutations.

Note that $\sigma$ permutes the $\alpha_i$. That means that $$
\{\sigma(\alpha_1),\ldots,\sigma(\alpha_n)\} = \{\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_n\}.$$
Therefore,
$$\begin{align*}
\sigma(g) &= \sigma\left(\prod_{i=1}^n (x-\alpha_i) \right)\\
& = \prod_{i=1}^n \sigma(x-\alpha_i) &\text{(}\sigma\text{ is a homomorphism)}\\
&= \prod_{i=1}^n (x-\sigma(\alpha_i)) &\text{(}\sigma\text{ is a homomorphism)}\\
&= \prod_{j=1}^n (x-\alpha_j) &\text{(}\sigma\text{ permutes the }\alpha_i\text{)}\\
&= g.
\end{align*}$$
Since $\sigma(g)=g$, that means the coefficients of $g$ are fixed by $\sigma$.
As this holds for all $\sigma\in G$, the coefficients of $g$ lie in the fixed field of $G$, $E^G$, which by assumption is $F$.

Makes sense, thank you!!
